# How to match pattern that contains substring

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this text:

```
Testing some text {{ first_name | mask }} and another {{ city }} and again {{ state | mask_trail }}
```

I would like to match only the `{{}}` that contain a pipe `|`

But when I do something like

```
text.scan(/({{.*?\|+.*?}})/)
```

`{{city}}` also gets matched

Comment: You may use a simpler `/{{(?:(?!{{).)*?\|.*?}}/`

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use this regex,

```
{{(?:(?!{{).)*\|(?:(?!{{).)*}}
```

**Explanation:**

- `{{` - Matches literal `{{`
- `(?:(?!{{).)*` - Matches any text except literal `{{` also called [Tempered Greedy Token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)
- `\|` - Matches pipe `|` character
- `(?:(?!{{).)*` -Again matches any text except literal `{{`
- `}}` - Matches literal `}}`

**[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/LEYPuF/1)**

Also, in case there are nested patterns like that, and you want to match the inner most patterns, you can use this regex,

```
{{(?:(?!{{|}}).)*\|(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}}
```

**[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LEYPuF/2)**

Check out this Ruby code,

```
re = /{{(?:(?!{{|}}).)*\|(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}}/
str = 'Testing some text{{ {{ first_name | mask }} }} and another {{ city }} and again {{ state | mask_trail }}'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Outputs,

```
{{ first_name | mask }}
{{ state | mask_trail }}
```

**[Online Ruby demo](https://rextester.com/FIKU80500)**

Comment: @EneaGUnlimApps: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume (in part because of the example in the question) that matches are to exclude strings beginning with "{{" and ending with "}}", containing "|", that also contain "{{". For example, neither

```
"{{ a | {{ b }}"
```

nor

```
"{{ a | {{ b }} c }}"
```

are to be matched. If these are to be matched, the regular expression suggested by @WiktorStribiżew in a comment on the question could be used.

You could obtain the desired matches as follows.

```
str = "Testing some text {{ first_name | mask }} and another {{ city }} " +
      "and again {{ state | mask_trail }}"

R = /
    {{         # match '{{'
    ((?!{{).)  # match one character not preceded by '{{'. Save in capture group 1
    *          # perform capture to group 1 zero or more times 
    \|         # match '|'
    \g<1>      # execute subroutine defined by capture group 1
    *          # perform preceding match zero or more times
    }}         # match '}}'
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

or, in short form,

```
R = /{{((?!{{).)*\|\g<1>*}}/
```

```
str.gsub(R).to_a
  #=> ["{{ first_name | mask }}", "{{ state | mask_trail }}"]
```

I could not use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) because I did not want to return the contents of the capture group. I therefore used [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) without a block to return an enumerator that generates matches, and then converted that to an array of matches. [Here](https://www.regexbuddy.com/manual.html#insertrecurse) is a discussion of regex subroutines or subexpressions.

I borrowed `(?!{{).` from @Pushpesh's answer.